# Can an automatic voice be programmed for a Discord music bot?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So, the title basically explains my question for my Discord bot in a brief form. More specifically, if a music track comes first in queue and it doesn't follow the guild-configured guidelines such as if it contains profanity, the audio has an approved copyright infringement complaint submitted to us through the bot's website by the original publisher prohibiting listening to the audio or it's a screamer, it will automatically say a message such as the following:

> The current music scheduled to play at this time is too intense in volume or exceeds the frequency limits for pitch. Skipping to next music in queue.
>
> The current music scheduled to play at this time has been marked for containing profane language and does not comply with the guild-configured guidelines. Skipping to next music in queue.
>
> The current music scheduled to play at this time has a copyright infringement complaint which indicates that the original publisher restricts listening to the audio. Skipping to next music in queue.

Would it be possible to program and automatic voice for a Discord bot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is trivial to send an audio file, and you don't seem to need dynamic speech generation; just prerecord the message and dump it into Discord as needed? If you do need text-to-speech, there's `google-tts-api`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

I'll help you implement user Amadan's idea into discord.py, first you'll need to install the google text to speech python api:

```
pip install gtts
```

This answer will assume that you're **not** using the rewrite branch of discord.py.

```
import os
import discord
from gtts import gTTS

if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
    # or libopus.so on linux in the current directory
    # you should replace this with the location the
    # opus library is located in and with the proper filename.
    discord.opus.load_opus('opus')

if not os.path.exists('message1.mp3'):

    tts = gTTS("The current music scheduled to play at this time is too intense in volume or exceeds "
               "the frequency limits for pitch. Skipping to next music in queue.")
    with open('message1.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        tts.write_to_fp(f)

if not os.path.exists('message2.mp3'):
    tts = gTTS("The current music scheduled to play at this time has been marked for containing profane"
               " language and does not comply with the guild-configured guidelines. "
               "Skipping to next music in queue.")
    with open('message2.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        tts.write_to_fp(f)

if not os.path.exists('message3.mp3'):
    tts = gTTS("The current music scheduled to play at this time has a copyright infringement complaint "
               "which indicates that the original publisher restricts listening to the audio. "
               "Skipping to next music in queue.")
    with open('message3.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        tts.write_to_fp(f)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, num):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.voice_channel

    voice = await bot.join_voice_channel(vc)

    player = voice.create_ffmpeg_player('message{}.mp3'.format(num))
    player.start()
```

Now in discord, when you are in a voice channel and type `<prefix>play <num>`, where prefix is the bot prefix and num (1-3) is the index of the message you want to play, the bot will say the message.

Comment: Note that since these are all static messages, it makes sense to at least cache them, if not outright pre-record them.

Comment: @Amadan They are pre-recorded, these command with gTTS only get ran once during the initial initiation of the bot. It stores the message recordings in a file, there's even a check in place for if the message files exist, it can skip the gTTS part.

Comment: I'm not sure you should be writing solutions for the OP - isn't the point to guide them with answers to specific questions and then help them debug specific, testable issues with their code?

Comment: @ACascarino the answer follows the general guidelines defined in the [help] and [answer]. I answered this question the way I had because the OP shown clues that they are confused on where/how to start and needed help. The solution I provided is fairly general and can appeal to a wide arrange of audiences. This can help save them the time and effort to dig through everything and find the solution themselves. I don't support answering questions where there's obvious dupes available, clear lack of research is shown on simple/relatively simple topics, or request for code on very specific subject.

Comment: @abccd I see, thank you for the guidance! I guess I find it difficult to know what crosses the line into a lack of research on a simple topic and/or a request for code on a specific subject - to my eyes this question looked exactly like that, framed in a slightly different way ("Is it possible to do X" rather than "how do I do X", but the implication is the same); there doesn't appear to be any research on the practicalities, nor is it a particularly broad application, but as I say I don't think I yet understand where that line is!